# jQuery: if an HTML element is not loaded, modify another one

Tags: jquery

I looked around and can't find anything similar to what I need help with.

--

I have two DIVs, floated to the left so they appear next to each other. In the left one I have the product image, and in the right one, the product description/information.

Sometimes, the product image will not appear in the page, that's because the product manager (there are many of them in the company I work at) may not have a picture of the product, hence, they won't upload a picture in the CMS, thus, in the product page only the description/information will appear.

**What I need**

What I need is a way to detect if the DIV of the product image has been injected in the page or not.

If it has, no problem, both containers maintain their widths. But if the DIV of the product image is not present on the page, then I need to modify the width of the DIV of the product description to be wider (otherwise, it will maintain its width and there will be unused space to its right).

Does that make sense?

Here's the basic code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="product-wrapper">Product image</div>
<div id="product-description">Product description/information</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#product-wrapper { float:left; width:200px; }
#product-description { float:left; width:400px; }
```

Thanks!

Comment: "But if the DIV of the product image is not present on the page" - is the DIV not there or is it empty? Is this content being loaded via AJAX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using just CSS?

For example if the elements are siblings, something like this may work.

You'll need to test in IE to make sure the `+` selector is working properly.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/j6zsL/ *(Remove the `product-wrapper` element, and click Run. You'll see that the `product-description` will become wider.)*

```
#product-wrapper { 
    float:left; 
    width:200px; 
    height: 200px;
    background: orange;​
}
#product-description { 
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    width:600px;
    background:red;
}

#product-wrapper + #product-description {
    width:400px;
}
```

Here the default width for `product-description` is `600px`, but if it has a `product-wrapper` before it, it is `400px`.

Comment: Yep, this is the best solution of all. This does not work in IE6, but it doesn't matter, we are phasing out support for IE6 anyway. It does work in IE7 and IE8, which is a huge thing since I did not expect it to work on any IE at all. Thanks for your help patrick :D

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of the Adjacent Sibling Selector until now. Very cool. Looks like it does fail in IE6 though, and has some quirky bugs in IE7. See "Compatibility" under http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector. If crappy IE service is not necessary, this is definitely the right solution.

Comment: @Ricardo - You're welcome. You can always do a little javascript to target IE6 using conditional comments. :o)

Comment: @Ben - It's fairly new to me as well. Always fun finding CSS that can eliminate a little js.

Answer (score 3):

One way is:

```
if ($('#product-wrapper img').length)
{
  ...
}
```

This assumes that the img tag is not present, rather than a broken image link.

Comment: Well, the entire DIV wouldn't be present. This solution worked, but patrick dw's solution worked better for me. Gave it a vote though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!$("#product-wrapper").length){ $("#product-description").width(600) }
```

Comment: better not to hard code "600" here. should add a class and make a corresponding change to the css (200 and 400 are defined in the css, so 600 should be as well). see the solution i posted.

Comment: Yes, this solution worked fine, even with the hard coded property and value in it. But patrick dw's solution worked better for me. Gave it a vote though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the image is not present, the entire `product-wrapper` div will not be on the page, correct?

You can attempt to get the element, and see if that succeeds.

The standard JS way would be

```
if(document.getElementById('product-wrapper')){/* do something */}
```

With jQuery,

```
if($('#product-wrapper').length){/* do something */}
```

The jQuery selector function returns an array. If the array has anything in it, the above will return true, and thus the element exists.

Comment: Yep, this one worked. But patrick dw's solution worked better for me. Gave it a vote too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your javascript:

```
if ($('#product-wrapper').length == 0) {
  $('product-description').addClass('wide');
}
```

And this to your CSS:

```
#product-description.wide {
  width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Hey Ben, you're solution is great and it was the one I was expecting. However, patrick dw's solution using only CSS works a lot better for what I need. Thanks a lot though :)

Comment: It's not letting me edit. Just wanted to say I gave you a vote too :)

Comment: @Ricardo Zea. Thanks. I agree that patrick dw's solution is the right one though -- I just wasn't aware of that CSS selector before.